# SeaweedFS Timeout exception

Tags: timeout, weed-fs, seaweedfs

I was searching file storage lib for store my big datas. So I've found SeaweedFS and it looks very good for my project. I use windows bash for test on my localhost but I got error based on timeout issue.

**Command**

```
./weed server -master.port=9333 -volume.port=8080 -dir="./data"
```

**Log**

```
I0513 18:03:48 12524 file_util.go:20] Folder ./data Permission: -rwxrwxrwx
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master.go:150] current: 169.254.255.169:9555 peers:169.254.255.169:9555
I0513 18:03:48 12524 file_util.go:20] Folder ./data Permission: -rwxrwxrwx
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master_server.go:108] Volume Size Limit is 30000 MB
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master_server.go:196] adminScripts:
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master.go:113] Start Seaweed Master 30GB 1.77 at 0.0.0.0:9555
I0513 18:03:48 12524 disk_location.go:117] Store started on dir: ./data with 0 volumes max 7
I0513 18:03:48 12524 disk_location.go:120] Store started on dir: ./data with 0 ec shards
I0513 18:03:48 12524 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:27] Volume server start with seed master nodes: [169.254.255.169:9555]
I0513 18:03:48 12524 raft_server.go:47] Starting RaftServer with 169.254.255.169:9555
I0513 18:03:48 12524 raft_server.go:51] Peers Change: [] => [169.254.255.169:9555]
I0513 18:03:48 12524 volume.go:279] Start Seaweed volume server 30GB 1.77 at 0.0.0.0:5001
I0513 18:03:48 12524 raft_server.go:74] Initializing new cluster
I0513 18:03:48 12524 raft_server.go:87] current cluster leader: 169.254.255.169:9555
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master_server.go:151] [ 169.254.255.169:9555 ] I am the leader!
I0513 18:03:48 12524 master.go:137] Start Seaweed Master 30GB 1.77 grpc server at 0.0.0.0:19555
I0513 18:04:08 12524 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:68] SendHeartbeat to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:08 12524 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:48] heartbeat error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:08 12524 masterclient.go:75] master failed to keep connected to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:08 12524 masterclient.go:118] master failed to connect with master 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:09 12524 masterclient.go:75] master failed to keep connected to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:09 12524 masterclient.go:118] master failed to connect with master 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:29 12524 masterclient.go:75] master failed to keep connected to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:29 12524 masterclient.go:118] master failed to connect with master 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:30 12524 masterclient.go:75] master failed to keep connected to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:30 12524 masterclient.go:118] master failed to connect with master 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:33 12524 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:68] SendHeartbeat to 169.254.255.169:9555: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
I0513 18:04:33 12524 volume_grpc_client_to_master.go:48] heartbeat error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 169.254.255.169:19555: i/o timeout"
```

I couldn't find any solution on internet.

Comment: What is your question and how is it related to [tag:elixir]?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I made a mistake about tags, sorry about that. As you can see from the logs I've problem on create connection for master and volume server.

Comment: where does the number 9555 come from? your command line does not match your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first run you've to change some configurations which defaults not for your localhost.

**Setting local**

```
./weed master -ip="localhost"
```

**Setting volume server**

```
./weed volume -port="yourPort"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove anything under "./data" folder and restart.